# Path with first degree relations in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I've a huge (20*10^6 nodes) network, and I would like to return a path from node a to node b, let's say of length 4. My problem is that I also need to display the children of the traversed nodes.
I can easily find a path with :

```
public Path getPath( final Node nodeA, final Node nodeB, int depth )
{
    PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths(
            Traversal.expanderForAllTypes(Direction.OUTGOING), depth);
    Path path = finder.findSinglePath( nodeA, nodeB );
    return path;
}
```

However, I would like to have the first degree children of each traversed node too. 
Problem #1 is that is not possible to add to the path.

```
for (Node n: path.nodes()){
   path.add(n.childrens())
 }
```

what is the best way to tackle this in neo4j for java?
or: 
how to implement path.add()?
- I've not understood how PathExpander should work;
- I've tried with the following, but I'm stuck:

```
public void expand_path(Node X){
    final TraversalDescription TRAVERSAL = Traversal.description()
        .breadthFirst()
        .relationships(MyTypes.LOVE)
        .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(1))
        .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL);

    for (Node n :TRAVERSAL.traverse(X).nodes()){
            //HELP!!!
        }

}
```

- I also have tried for couple of hours with cypher queries but I honestly I've no idea on how to achieve this.

[image]

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to add those children nodes to the path. As it can be seen from your second graph, the nodes on the path together with the children nodes form multiple paths rather than a single path.

There are two things I can think of that might be helpful towards your goal,

One is to get the path and iterate the nodes on the path as you already did, for each node, get the relationship for the desired type, then get the other end node(the child node) for the node on the path,

```
for ( Node nodeOnPath : path.nodes() ) 
{
    Relationship rel = nodeOnPath.getSingleRelationship(MyTypes.LOVE,  Direction.INCOMING)   
    Node childNode = rel.getOtherNode(nodeOnPath)
    // process the childNode
}
```

This way you get access to each node on the path, and also its child node.

Another is to get every path that leads to the end node with the traversal framework, and extend each path with additional relationship of type "MyTypes.Love" to include the child node to the path by using **ExtendedPath.extend(path, loveRelationship)**.

Concretely, suppose you have two given node "a" and "d", and a path between "a" and "d", a<-b<-c<-d.

You would get the following paths and the extended paths

a<-b,  a<-b<-childOfb
a<-b<-c, a<-b<-c<-childOfC
a<-b<-c<-d,  a<-b<-c<-d<-childOfd

The sample code to implement this is as follows,

```
TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description()
              .depthFirst()
              .relationships(RelTypes.REL, Direction.INCOMING)
              .evaluator(new Evaluator() {
                @Override
                public Evaluation evaluate(final Path path) {
                    Node endNode = path.endNode();
                    if ( endNode.getProperty("name").equals('d') ){
                       return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
                                        }
                    else {
                       return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                    }

                }
            });

for ( Path path : td.traverse(aNode) ) {
   Iterator<Relationship> iter = endNode.getRelationships(RelTypes.LOVE,Direction.INCOMING).iterator();
  if ( iter.hasNext() ) {
     Path extendedPath = ExtendedPath.extend(path, iter.next());
     for ( Node enode :  extendedPath.nodes() )
         System.out.print(enode.getProperty("name") + "---");       
   }
}
```